# Operations on Simple Array of Unknown Type

Tags: java, arrays

In my Java program, I have a class with three private arrays as properties:

```
private byte[] code;
private CustomClass[] locals;
private int[] lines;
```

Though these three arrays have different types, I am performing identical operations on all three at various points in the program -- for example, "insert a new element at position N."

Assume that I need to continue defining these properties as simple arrays -- i.e. I can't use a Java Collections object instead.  Is there a way to create a class that encapsulates and defines operations on a simple array without knowing what type of objects are in the array?  I have read that it is unsafe to use Java generics with a simple array, otherwise I would try that.

Comment: You mean reflection, maybe `System.arraycopy`?

Comment: "*I am performing identical operations on all three at various points in the program -- for example, "insert a new element at position N."*" this looks like you should have some class for each of those 3 data chunks like `class MyClass { /*byte, CustomClass, int fields */ }` , and have one array of that class `MyClass[] array`.

Comment: What does "insert a new element at position N" mean? How can you perform "identical operations" when the data types are all different? Is the usage something like: `addToAllArrays(someByte, someCustomClass, someInt)`?

Comment: Semantically identical operations.  For example, I am often inserting a new element of the corresponding type into each array at some position other than the end.  Such as: lines.insert(14, 43); or locals.insert(9, new CustomClass());